# How can I make a separator between rows of row in List View?

Tags: android, listview

I want to make a list view of names. But I need know how can I put the letter A in the top of rows that start with A and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Section Adapter here are some links with full source that could help you.

[How ListView works with complete example including a seperator](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296)

[Section Adapter source code](https://github.com/monxalo/android-section-adapter)

**UPDATE:**

You can also use ExpandableList for the same

[ExpandableListActivity Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/extendsBaseExpandableListAdapter.htm)

[Expandable list with CWAC](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/03/expandable-list-with-cwac.html)

Answer (score 0):

@Hello What you are looking for it is show in this [Click Here](http://androidseverywhere.info/JAAB/?p=6) and you can also use this Green Droid Library to get Good UI Support.  Here link of Green Droid lib [Green Droid link](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid)